# How can I integrate an Azure API into an internal framework?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication

I'm trying to find a way to integrate the ability to change the service tier of an Azure SQL database into an internal company framework.

I found this api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/update), which I believe will do what I want by updating the service tier.

I am trying to work through Microsoft's Azure API overview, but don't have the background knowledge required to point myself in the right direction (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/). Currently I am working on figuring out how to authenticate with OAuth2 using this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code)

I can get an access token when using the HttpClient class, but get the following errors when trying to use it to get the bearer token. There are very few references to these errors elsewhere for this use which makes me think I am approaching this incorrectly.

```
"SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found" 
"HttpRequestException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"
```

Additionally, I also tried to use the quickstart guide under Azure Active Directory for creating a .NET console app/daemon authenticated with a client secret and without specific user credentials. When following this I get the following error.

```
Token acquired
Failed to call the Web Api: Unauthorized
Content: {
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
    "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d2a863e0-d2bc-4bc6-9855-8ff23743e7d1",
      "date": "2019-04-05T21:57:33"
    }
  }
}
```

Any guidance is appreciated - especially regarding whether I am even using the right approach or not.